# Find the matrix of linear map in standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the matrix of linear map $L: M_{2x2} \rightarrow M_{2x2}$ which is given by formula $L(x) = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1\\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}x$ in standard basis.

As I assume the standard basis of $M_{2x2}$ is

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, but how do I find matrix of this linear map with matrix spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might mean
$$
L(x) = A X
$$
for $X \in M_{2\times 2}$ and not $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, assuming matrix multiplication of $A$ and $X$.

In this case the sought matrix is the image of the standard base of $M_{2\times 2}$, which consists of the usual four matrices $M_i$. Each image is a $2\times 2$ matrix, which has to be mapped to a $4$-vector.

$$
M = (A M_1, A M_2, A M_3, A M_4)
$$

Answer (score 3):

A matrix $X$ ,represented in standard basis, is :
$$
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2\\x_3&x_4
\end {bmatrix}=
x_1\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end {bmatrix}
+x_2\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end {bmatrix}
+x_3\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\1&0
\end {bmatrix}
+x_4\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\0&1
\end {bmatrix}
$$
so it can be represented as a vector:
$\vec X=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end {bmatrix}$

and the given linear transformation acts as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end {bmatrix} \to
L(X)=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2&1\\3&4
\end {bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1&x_2\\x_3&x_4
\end {bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2x_1+x_3&-2x_2+x_4\\3x_1+4x_3&3x_2+4x_4
\end {bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2x_1+x_3\\-2x_2+x_4\\3x_1+4x_3\\3x_2+4x_4
\end {bmatrix} =\vec {L(X)}
$$

Now a simple inspection gives you the $4 \times 4$ matrix that represents $L$:
$$
L=\begin{bmatrix}
-2&0&1&0\\
0&-2&0&1\\
3&0&4&0\\
0&3&0&4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ is a basis, the matrix of an operator $A$ in that basis is given by the coefficients 
$$
Ae_j=\sum_k a_{kj}e_k. 
$$

In your case, if you label the basis $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$ in the order you gave above, 
$$
L(E_{1})=\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\3&4\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -2&0\\3&0\end{bmatrix}=-2E_1+3E_3.
$$
So the first row of the matrix is $-2,0,3,0$. Now you do the same for the other three basis elements.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix for $L$ is $4\times4$. Write $L(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix})$ as a combination of $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$  The coefficients give you the first row.  Do the same for the other three.